# run a python script on windows command promt

Tags: python, windows, prompt

I want to create a short cut on my windows desktop to run Anaconda prompt and execute a python file.
I have the following which opens the Conda prompt just fine:

```
%windir%\System32\cmd.exe "/K" C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3
```

but subsequently i want to run this python file (C:\Users\Administrator.spyder-py3\temp2.py) as well so I added "&" to it:

```
%\System32\cmd.exe "/K" C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3 & C:\Users\Administrator\.spyder-py3\temp2.py
```

But this is giving me an error saying "python file not found", and I know this is a correct file and path.
Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: It's not obvious why running "C:\Users\Administrator\.spyder-py3\temp2.py" would return "python file not found", unless maybe the .py file association is configured in some unusual way.

Comment: You should be able to directly run a .py file from the command prompt without having to explicitly run "python.exe". If .py files are associated with the "py.exe" launcher, and "temp2.py" either has no shebang, or a "python" virtual shebang (not "python3"), such as "#!/usr/bin/python", then the launcher will run the python.exe executable from the environment that's activated by activate.bat. It can't be a "python3" shebang because, as designed, the launcher will only run a registered Python 3 for that case, not the executable from the active environment.

Answer (score 1):

well, I figured it out. I forgot to also add "python" right before the python file so it  know that it needs python driver to execute the file:

```
%windir%\System32\cmd.exe "/K" C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3 & python C:\Users\Administrator\.spyder-py3\temp2.py
```